# A Function Meromorphic with Poles at the Primes

Tags: number-theory, complex-analysis

Is there a "naturally occurring" function $f$ which is meromorphic in the complex plane such that the poles of $f$ on the real axis are precisely at the primes? I say "naturally occurring" since we can always cook up a function with the right poles of the right order, but I would hope that it comes from number theory.

Alternatively, is there a naturally arising meromorphic function whose poles appear at all primes and powers of primes?

Comment: What you mean is «meromorphic function with poles at the primes», not «meromorphic at the primes».

Comment: no there isnt...

Comment: Fixed the title

Comment: Can you construct a function with poles at the integers?

Comment: Yes, the Weierstrass $\mathfrak{p}$ function for the integer lattice will have poles at exactly the integers. The poles will be order 2, but at least for now I won't put any restrictions on that.

Comment: Weierstrass would have poles at the Gaussian integers, no?

Comment: Sure, but I'm only asking that the poles occurring on the real axis be at the primes (or in that case the integers). There are in principal many meromorphic functions satisfying this condition, which is why I am looking for one that shows up "naturally" in number theory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $P(s) = \sum_{p} p^{-s}$ be the [Prime zeta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_zeta_function).

**Claim:**  the series expansion $$f(z) = 2 \sum_{n=1}^\infty P(2n)z^{2n-1}$$ defines a meromorphic function whose only poles are simple poles of residue $1$ at the primes and their negatives.

Let $F(z) = \prod_ p (1-z^2/p^2)^{-1}$. The product converges uniformly on compact subsets of $\mathbf C - P$, where $P$ is the set of all primes and their negatives. Therefore it is holomorphic there. It has simple poles at the points of $P$. (Note the special value $F(1) = \zeta(2) = \pi^2/6$).

Using the series expansion for $\log(1-x)$, we have the series expansion for $\log F$, $$\log F(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{P(2n)}{n}z^{2n}.$$

Taking the derivative we get $f(z)$. Since the poles of $F$ are simple and $F$ is never $0$ on $\mathbf C - P$ (on account of the convergence of the product), $f = F'/F$ has simple poles with residue $1$ at the points of $P$, and no other poles.

Comment: And this function is "naturally occuring"?

Comment: @mrf Up to a unit of the ring of holomorphic functions on $\mathbf C$, it is unique! :)